# setting default page in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net

We have a asp.net app, in which index.aspx is the default document in the website, instead of default.aspx. 
Index.aspx is set as start page in the project too. but when I am trying to open for example: http://localhost:2265/, 1st I was getting the default.aspx page, after I removed the default.aspx file from the solution, now I have the directory listing displayed.
I would like to get index.aspx when I am entering http://localhost:2265/, is that possible to be set in the project or only in IIS?
Thanks in advance and happy holidays, Laziale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled from the server, which could either be IIS or the development server that's bundled with Visual Studio.

If you're launching the app from within Visual Studio, then the controls can probably be found under the properties of the ASP web site/app that you're launching. You could also right click the page itself and select "Set As Startup Page".

All of this doesn't affect the behaviour of the app once it's hosted in IIS, however. You'll need to find similar settings in the IIS page - there should be many a tutorial on the web for that (I can point you to one if you're having trouble).

Hope this clears up the behaviour of default pages!

Answer (score 0):

In your project right click on the page you want to be your landing page and click "Set as Start Page".

This will only work when you run it from Visual Studio though.  If you want to do it once it's deployed you will have to use IIS or setup a redirect I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Just open your solution in VS, then select the page you would like to be the startup page and do a right click and select 'Set As Start Page' option